# Best way to get original book volume with Google Books API

Tags: google-books-api

Was wondering if anyone had found a reliable way of accessing the first edition of a book via Google Books API (or another API for that matter)?

The idea here would be to get the first published date of a novel. For example Orwell's 1984 would be 1948, Lonesome Dove would be 1985.

Currently I can get the most relevant volume via a search but often it returns a newer edition.